# History of self-duets

Tags: history, self-duet, duet

The lockdowns associated with current coronavirus pandemic have sparked production of self-duets. The Austrian-German concert violinist Augustin Hadelich has released a lot of piano-violin self-duets on his [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9yWS3ViwScQOr7IbTc4LZ_iYjLIa1z39).

Back in 2016, fiddler Katy Adelson produced this interesting cello-violin self-duet -

Also back in 2016, Fran Guidry produced a [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNhzJoHGuUo) to producing video self-duets using Reaper on YouTube and in his [blog](http://www.homebrewedmusic.com/2016/10/04/self-duet-videos-in-reaper/).

Self-duets predate the YouTube era. Back in 2006 on the album "You Raise Me Up: The Best of Aled Jones" there was a track featuring the adult, baritone Aled Jones accompanying his younger treble self on his 1985 hit "Walking in the Air".

Is this the earliest recorded self-duet? Have many musical artists been producing self-duets before lockdown?

Comment: This sounds like it would be more fit on the Music Fans SE.

Comment: @Dom According to the help center (https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) "What topics can I ask about here?" - "music theory, notation, **history**, or composition". This is asking about music history

Comment: History _is_ on topic, but this seems more in vein of the history questions that are better cared for on the Music Fan SE (there are several questions on the music fan's SE about recording firsts). The question to me seems to be more about finding the earliest out of appreciation rather than the typical topics of the site. There's not necessarily a hard line, but it feels more towards the fan site. There have also been other discussions about what qualifies as a history question in the past: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2867/what-music-history-questions-are-on-and-off-topic

Comment: FYI, when I was studying for my Bar Mitzvah in 1973, my temple's cantor had released an album containing a song where he sang all 5 parts of a vocal quintet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Self-duets of the sort you have in mind are an example of "[overdubbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdubbing)", a technique allowing a musician to record one part and then record a second part while playing back the first. The technique goes back to the very early days of recording technology. Wikipedia has a [brief history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdubbing#History).

> Perhaps the earliest commercial issue of recordings with overdubs was by RCA Victor in the late 1920s, not long after the introduction of electric microphones into the recording studio. Recordings by the late Enrico Caruso still sold well, so RCA took some of his early records made with only piano accompaniment, added a studio orchestra, and reissued the recordings.

This is corroborated on the Victor Records website:

> Some highlights of [Nathaniel Shilkret's] career include ... conducting some of the first overdubbed recordings onto Enrico Caruso's voice. ([SOURCE](https://www.victorrecords.com/nathaniel-shilkret))

The earliest example of a "self-duet" mentioned in the Wikipedia article is [Sidney Bechet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Bechet)'s 1941 recording of "[The Sheik of Araby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTq8cOi1FCs)", on which he plays all of the instruments.

However, depending on how expansive you want the definition of "self-duet" to be, keyboardists have been playing self-duets since, at least, the invention of [counterpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterpoint) for those instruments. One obvious example is [the fugue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugue), which requires the keyboardist to play several "voices" simultaneously. For example, here is Bach's [Fugue in C Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dkt75juxvxw&t=1m57s) from *The Well-Tempered Clavier* Book 1 (BWV 846).

If you require one musician to play to separate instruments, then whoever invented the "one-man band" would be the originator of the self-duet. [This web article](https://www.mustrad.org.uk/articles/barrick.htm) places one-man bands as early as the 13th century.

> Certainly one of the oldest combinations of two instruments played simultaneously is the pipe and tabor, to which the earliest references appear in the 13th century.

Wikipedia [corroborates this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-man_band).

Comment: I would speculate that the "self-duet" is even older than the 13th century, and likely dates to the first time humans began creating music. Singing and clapping hands, for example, would be a "self-duet." There's also throat singing, which could be consider a form of self-duet.

Answer (score 3):

By no means the earliest, but I'm just dropping this in as about the only appropriate place we've ever had for this example.

This guy is Yattie Westfield, apparently out of Birmingham, Alabama. The only footage of him you ever find is shot on phones, so sound & picture isn't great, but once you got beyond the initial, *"WTF? OMG! Really? No!!"* this is quite a display of limb independence.